# azure VM Crushed, unavailable or not working correctly

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-cli, azure-monitoring

I want to get a webhook or a notification when one of my virtual machines is down or crashed or not working correctly, I was thinking about ping metric or something like that to know the state but there is no ping metric as I know, I don't know how to get that information using azure monitoring or other solutions?!

Answer (score 0):

The "older" metrics don't really provide a suitable metric for your needs. You would have to rely on CPU consumption or using an application or crashdump log as a source.

But you should check out the recently announced near-real time metric alerts. They allow you to configure metrics populated from log analytics, which allow a lot more flexibility in your case. For example, using heartbeat would probably be suitable for "ping".

Currently in preview:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-near-real-time-metric-alerts

Comment: i was thinking about ping metric or something like that to know the state but there is no ping metric as i know

Comment: Yes you are correct - there is no ping metric available. If you have the capability to use Log Analytics, having an agent configured and using the heartbeat metric there would provide pretty much the same result. It's not related to network connectivity itself, but rather to the state of your virtual machine. If the heartbeat fails, it pretty much means that something is wrong with your VM. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/operations-management-suite/oms-solution-agenthealth

Comment: unfortunately i can't assume the price of the operation using log analytics(i want to reduce price not the inverse) if there is any  other solution i 'll be more grateful